# How many "polygons" does my model have?

Tags: modeling, polycount

I have my model and in the info bar its show this
[image: blender's info bar showing the poly count]

May I need to know how many polygons it has, but  there is no option to find polygons. Verts, Edge and Faces nothing polygon option there.
In the website its say that the upload limit is 400,000 polygons. I did not get over that limit or how many polygons my model has?

Comment: You have boths *Faces* and *Tris* information, what else do you require?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the website say 400.000 polygons what polygon means face or verts or tris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you have a "poly limit" it is referring to triangles. You need look at Blender's *Tris* count.

A "face" is just two or more triangles (quad has two triangles, an N-gon has more) so the face count is not the real number.
If you make a model with only triangles, the face count and the Tris count will be the same.

Notice the face and triangle count in the images below.
This first cube is a default cube with 6 quads. The other cube has been triangulated. Notice the face and tri count match.
[image: normal cube] [image: triangulated cube]

This is an object consisting of a single N-gon, and nothing more.
[image: one n-gon]

Answer (score -2):

Your info bar that you inserted an image of has the "faces" information.  The number of faces shown is simply the total number of polygons in your scene, including all tris, quads, and n-gons.  So looking at the info, your model has over 3 million polygons.

Edit: as someone pointed out below, the polygon restriction likely refers to tris specifically, and as such your model has over 5 million (a quad is really 2 Tris, and ngons can have any number of tris).  All polygons are eventually split up into tris for rendering anyway, so looking at the number of tris is probably the most accurate number.

Comment: This is incorrect information, the number of faces is not the total number of polygons, and doesn't include tris nor quads. Faces can be triangles, quads, or NGons and have any number of triangles. In fact if you look the actual number of triangles is way higher. Polygons is a very vague term, it most likely refer to triangles, which is the only concise and absolute measurement of detail

Comment: Well, geometrically speaking, tris, quads, and ngons are all subsets of polygons.  A polygon is a shape containing any number of planar vertices/edges.  However, I will edit my response to clarify.