# What should be the mesh count when I submit a model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, edges, polycount

I have been planning to upload a 3D model lately. What is the actual definition of 
polygon numbers as I don't know what subdivision level is taken as the standard for my submission. The 3D website didn't state which subdivision level of my model
should be taken as the standard for polygon counting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It could be a bit opinion-based, but - 1) consider triangles or quads only, in the count: if your model has n-gons (5+ vertices) those should be retopologized/converted to tri/quad polygons only - 2) It also depends on the model inherent complexity, and the target usage: interactive (games) models that should be animated (characters) are better designed with the least (or suitable) amount of (good) geometry, static models (for stills) that should be the main subject are better designed with the more detail possible, and perfect topology is somewhat less important (except texturing easiness).

Comment: [How many “polygons” does my model have?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/96614/2217) apart from that we have no way of knowing how many you should have in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Polygon:** a plane figure with at least three straight sides and angles, and typically five or more.

The faces you see in blender are actually Polygons.

First of all you take account apply all modifier that are in .blend file.The site on which you're uploading the model usually show the guide "how to do that?".
Delete all unnecessary objects (like: camera,lights etc.).Secondly select your final model after applying all modifiers

[image]

[image]

You will see whole information about the Faces, Vertices, Edges count. No. of Faces will be the polygon count. There's no restriction on subdivision level what you used in blender that will be just okay!

Comment: This is not correct. The Face count is *not* the polygon count. See this answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96621/2217).